# "IsImage validation" or "MimeType Validator" in Zend Framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am using formFilter method (factory method) to validate forms in **Zend Framework 2**. Please somebody help to add file upload validation.

Please specify how to use "**IsImage validation**" or "**MimeType Validator**" inside formfilter.

Comment: Why are you looking at examples for ZF 1.12? The man page for ZF2 is here -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.validator.file.html

Comment: Additionally see here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748917/how-to-add-file-mimetype-validator-in-zend-framework-2-model-declaration

Comment: @Crisp you comment is good, Make it answer

Comment: Thanks Crisp for your reply. I have already used this, in this image validation is doing in controllers. Since I am doing all other validations in form filters, I am askign whether can I do this validations too in filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->filter) {
        $this->filter = new InputFilter();
        $factory = new InputFactory();
        $this->filter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name' => 'image',
                    'required' => true,
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                            'options' => array(
                                'messages' => array(
                                    'isEmpty' => 'Please select an icon to upload.',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => '\Zend\Validator\File\IsImage',
                            'options' => array(
                                'messages' => array(
                                    'fileIsImageFalseType' => 'Please select a valid icon image to upload.',
                                    'fileIsImageNotDetected' => 'The icon image is missing mime encoding, please verify you have saved the image with mime encoding.',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
        )));
    }
    return parent::getInputFilter();
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/3764)